# Adding onclick function to button in info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I need help to make the onclick function work in my `InfoWindow` content.

Here is a part of my code:

```js
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    var icon = {
        url:"http:///".concat(markers[i][3]),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][4].toString().concat(' ').concat(markers[i][5].toString()),
        icon: icon, 
        url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent('<p><label>Name:</label> '+this.title+'</p>' +
            '<center><button class="btn btn-primary" \n\
            onclick="myFunction(){ window.location.assign(this.url);}">Call</button></center>'); 
         infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Comment: In your onclick handler function "this" will refer to the button element not the marker. Why don't you use a <a> tag with href ?

Comment: i need the style of button

Comment: If you add <a> tag with class btn btn-primary it will look like a button

Comment: infowindow.setContent('<p><label>Name:</label> '+this.title+'</p>' +
                              '<center><a class="btn btn-primary" href="im:<sip:"+markers[i][6]+">Call</a></center>');

Comment: i can't go to that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onclick handler function **this** will refer to the button element not the marker object, that's why its not working since button not any property like url.

You can use a  tag with href to redirect to your desired location

Try this:

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
 var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
 var icon = {url:"http:///".concat(markers[i][3]),
             scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
             origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
             anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) };
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     title: markers[i][4].toString().concat(' ').concat(markers[i][5].toString()),
     icon: icon, 
     url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'
 });
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
 });
 marker.addListener('mouseover', function() { 
    infowindow.setContent('<p><label>Name:</label> '+this.title+'</p>' +
                          '<center><a class="btn btn-primary" href="'+this.url+'">Call</a></center>'); 
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` handler doesn't actually execute anything. You just define a function in it. Try this:

```js
 for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
     var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
     var icon = {url:"http:///".concat(markers[i][3]),
                 scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20), // scaled size
                 origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                 anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) };
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: position,
         map: map,
         title: markers[i][4].toString().concat(' ').concat(markers[i][5].toString()),
         icon: icon, 
         url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'
     });
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
     });
     marker.addListener('mouseover', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent('<p><label>Name:</label> '+this.title+'</p>' +
                              '<center><button class="btn btn-primary" \n\
                             onclick="window.location.assign(' + this.url + ');">Call</button></center>'); 
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
```

Comment: page not found and i redirected to this page *******/search/undefined

Comment: i didn't go to this link :  url:'im:<sip:'+markers[i][6]+'>'  and i got missing argument )